# How to build a web application for python>?

Tags: python-3.x, voice

I'm building a voice assistant using python. I want to make it available as a web application. How do I build the same?

Thanks

Comment: Have you investigated Python web frameworks like Django and Flask? Stack Overflow isn't really meant for questions seeking recommendations like this.

Comment: Start here https://youtu.be/MwZwr5Tvyxo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask is a good framework and you can combine with Google App Engine to deploy it:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/

Answer (score 0):

You can also run Python web hosting if you're looking for the absolute easiest way to do it: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/